# Encoding in Java ESAPI

Tags: java, esapi

To prevent from SQL injections,  [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Escaping_Dynamic_Queries) encodes characters received.Below is the code implemented for org.owasp.esapi.codecs.OracleCodec.java class

```
 //Default implementation that should be overridden in specific codecs. Encodes ' to '' Encodes ' to '' (according to doc)


 public String encodeCharacter( char[] immune, Character c ) {
    if ( c.charValue() == '\'' )
        return "\'\'";
    return ""+c;
}
```

How does above help for the prevention of SQL injection?Please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the guidelines at OWASP, multiple test cases can be found [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_SQL_Injection_%28OWASP-DV-005%29#Standard_SQL_Injection_Testing).

The snippet of code you're looking at here defends against someone trying to escape out of the query to run their own arbitrary command.

```
if ( c.charValue() == '\'' )
```

If the input value is equal to ASCII char value `0x27` (a single quote)

```
return "\'\'";
```

Escape the single quote.

Oracle escaping is [here](http://www.orafaq.com/faq/how_does_one_escape_special_characters_when_writing_sql_queries).

Lets say your query is `"select * from users where id = \'" + request.getParameter("id")`

By not escaping single-quotes, an input like this:

`request.setParameter("id", "\' OR 1=1;");` would result in returning all the information in that table by changing the final, non-Java formatted query to `select * from users where id = '' OR 1=1;`

I highly recommend you download the [WebGoat](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_WebGoat_Project) program, and follow its lessons.  It will teach you how to use SQL injection, and many other basic web attacks.  And the ESAPI swingset will help you learn how to mitigate them.

Answer (score 1):

Here explains very well for oracle and others DBMS:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

But rule n. 1 to prevent SQL injection is not to use query concatenation but instead prepared statements! With prepared statements there is no need to encode any parameter (set by sql api) and there are also DB performance optimizations.