# Why I am getting 'missing right parenthesis' error here?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, esapi

My SQL queries are dynamically generated by ESAPI encoder by using Oracle codec. Below is one of the sample queries.

`SELECT * FROM EX_TABLE WHERE START_DATE = TO_DATE(''11-Jan-22'',''DD-MM-YY'');`

Currently getting **ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis** error for it.

If I try to execute the query by removing the extra `'` sign it works fine. For Example:

`SELECT * FROM EX_TABLE WHERE START_DATE = TO_DATE('11-Jan-22','DD-MM-YY');`

I will not be able to remove those extra `'` signs as it is generated by ESAPI encoder to avoid SQL injection. I can't figure out why those extra `'` are causing this issue.

Comment: It's causing issues because it is invalid syntax. You don't fix sql injection by inserting more "stuff" into the queries. You fix it by using prepared statements and bind variables.

Comment: @Mat actually this kind of code is generated by a java encoder called ESAPI encoder. example - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23336957/encoding-in-java-esapi) . So currently trying to figure out if I can still process this statement. I

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with the ESAPI code you are using to generate that statement, the values you input into the ESAPI code, and the expected output. You know that the problem is with the double quotes so something needs changing in yout ESAPI code to stop it generating the double quotes but we can't tell you what needs changing unless you provide a (minimal) example of the code you are using.

Comment: @MT0 I will edit it and add minimum code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Either that API is broken, or you're using it incorrectly. You double up single quotes _inside_ a string literal if you need a literal single quote. Doubling the string delimiter itself is just a plain syntax error. Either way, investing your time in bind variables and prepared statements would be of much higher value than trying to fudge SQL with escaping tricks.

Comment: ESAPI's SQL Encoders were designed only as an emergency band-aid to help a hacked website limp through to give time for complicated SQL queries to be rewritten as parameterized SQL queries.  Further, it sounds like you might be running an entire query through the encoder which is NOT the proper use case.  If you MUST use the encoders here encode *the data* and not the code.  If the application is receiving fully formed SQL statements as data then there's something even more terribly wrong unless this is an SQL IDE.